# The getter 'value' was called on null

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create this font size animation in flutter but I am receiving the following error: The getter 'value' was called on null.

It seems weird because I have another dart file with similar code and it works perfectly.

***Any help would be strongly appreciated.***

```
Animation<double> _fontSizeAnimation;
AnimationController _fontSizeAnimationController;
```

initState function():

```
super.initState();
_fontSizeAnimationController = new AnimationController(
    duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
_fontSizeAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _fontSizeAnimationController, curve: Curves.bounceOut);
_fontSizeAnimation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));
_fontSizeAnimationController.forward();
```

Material widget

```
  return new Material(
  color: Colors.blueAccent,
  child: new InkWell(
    onTap: () => print("We tapped the page!"),
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text("Let's Quizzz",
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: _fontSizeAnimation.value * 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        new Text("Tap to start!",
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: It means `_fontSizeAnimation` is `null when `fontSize: _fontSizeAnimation.value * 15,` is executed. It's hard to tell from the code you posted why it's `null`

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same null warning. Changing _fontSizeAnimation.value works without null error ...

```
  children: <Widget>[
    new Text("Let's Quizzz",
        style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: (_fontSizeAnimation.value + 1) * 15,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    new Text("Tap to start!",
        style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can null coalesce the `_fontSizeAnimation.value` into

```
_fontSizeAnimation?.value ?? 0 * 15
```